# How to get the first part of the string in bash

Tags: bash, substring

Say I have the following file names from an `ls` in a bash script:

```
things-hd-91-Statistics.db
things.things_domain_idx-hd-38-Data.db
```

In bash, how would it be able to get the first part of the string `'things'` in either case?
Basically remove the rest of the string past the first `-` or `.`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

```
string="things-hd-91-Statistics.db"
echo "${string%%-*}"
things
```

Where in `${parameter%%pattern}` the 'pattern' (`-*`) is matched against the end of 'parameter'. The result is the expanded value of 'parameter' with the longest match deleted.

Similarly for your other example, the pattern would be `%%.*`

Comment: Or, combining the two in one: `${string%%[-.]*}`.